# HTML-Text-Field-Validation on Date-Entries

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, textfield

My problem is that I haven't written a HTML-field-validation yet, but have to write one that checks if an text-input-field has an date-entry in format dd.mm.yyyy and if so, if the date is in a certain range.

If any of those conditions is not true, the cursor shall be immediately forced back to the entry-field, so the user can repeat his input correctly.

I know that I could code this in jQuery-UI (datepicker), and this would be my choice if I had the choice, but my boss wants manual input.

Maybe someone has a link to a code-snippet in the web that I haven't found so far.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks alot for your support.

konsti

Answer (score 1):

[You can refer to this link](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-date-validation.php) . Date validation function in javascript is

```
function validatedate(inputText)
  {
  var dateformat = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;
  // Match the date format through regular expression
  if(inputText.value.match(dateformat))
  {
  document.form1.text1.focus();
  //Test which seperator is used '/' or '-'
  var opera1 = inputText.value.split('/');
  var opera2 = inputText.value.split('-');
  lopera1 = opera1.length;
  lopera2 = opera2.length;
  // Extract the string into month, date and year
  if (lopera1>1)
  {
  var pdate = inputText.value.split('/');
  }
  else if (lopera2>1)
  {
  var pdate = inputText.value.split('-');
  }
  var dd = parseInt(pdate[0]);
  var mm  = parseInt(pdate[1]);
  var yy = parseInt(pdate[2]);
  // Create list of days of a month [assume there is no leap year by default]
  var ListofDays = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
  if (mm==1 || mm>2)
  {
  if (dd>ListofDays[mm-1])
  {
  alert('Invalid date format!');
  return false;
  }
  }
  if (mm==2)
  {
  var lyear = false;
  if ( (!(yy % 4) && yy % 100) || !(yy % 400)) 
  {
  lyear = true;
  }
  if ((lyear==false) && (dd>=29))
  {
  alert('Invalid date format!');
  return false;
  }
  if ((lyear==true) && (dd>29))
  {
  alert('Invalid date format!');
  return false;
  }
  }
  }
  else
  {
  alert("Invalid date format!");
  document.form1.text1.focus();
  return false;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Hi,

 thanks for fast reply. ;)

That is exactly what i had in mind.

greetings
konsti

Comment: @konsti this code is helpful for you then plz accept and upvote it.

Comment: i surely would accept and upvote, but i'm quite new at stackoverflow.com and stil don't know how to.